# objective c - how to get elements dynamically from NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the json file below and I save it in an array by doing

```
NSArray *allFrames = [self.campaign.form.gameParams objectForKey:@"frames"];
```

What I want to achieve, is to place all the horizontal images from the url in a view. My problem is I want to do this dynamically, because the number of the elements may change.

```
  frames =     (
            {
        horizontal = "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/5_h.png";
        vertical = "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/5_v.png";
    },

            {
        horizontal = "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_h.png";
        vertical = "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_v.png";
    }
            {
        horizontal = "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_h.png";
        vertical = "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_v.png";
    }
);
```

What I have done until now is to store the urls statically like this

```
    NSDictionary *frames = allFrames[0];

    NSString * link1 = [frames objectForKey:@"horizontal"];


    NSDictionary *frames = allFrames[1];

    NSString * link2 = [frames objectForKey:@"horizontal"];


    NSDictionary *frames = allFrames[2];

    NSString * link3 = [frames objectForKey:@"horizontal"];
```

And then convert the urls into images

```
    UIImage *webImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:
                                   [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:link1]]]; 
                                                               etc
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Iterate over the array...

Comment: can you explain? I am new at this

Comment: I simply can't believe Google didn't come up with something useful. This question is repeated a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < allFrames.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = allFrames[i];
    NSString *link = dict[@"horizontal"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]]];

    [imageArray addObject:image];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

horizontal data can be filtered using  valueForKey of NSArray.

```
NSArray *horizontalImages = [frames valueForKey:@"horizontal"];

for(NSString *urlString in horizontalImages)
{
UIImage *webImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:
                                   [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *dict = @[@{@"horizontal": @"http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/5_h.png"}, @{@"horizontal": @"http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_h.png"}, @{@"horizontal": @"http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_h.png"}];
NSMutableArray *horizontalLinks = [NSMutableArray array];
[dict enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [horizontalLinks addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"horizontal"]];
}];

NSLog(@"Horizontal Links: %@", horizontalLinks);
```

Will give you:

```
Horizontal Links: (
    "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/5_h.png",
    "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_h.png",
    "http://mysite.co.uk/files/frames/6_h.png"
)
```